# Find the number of multi-subsets of $M = \{r_1a_1,r_2a_2,...,r_na_n\}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of multi-subsets of $M = \{r_1a_1,r_2a_2,...,r_na_n\}$. If someone is simply unaware of the term multi-subsets I am asking for the number of all combinations of $M$ where repetitions are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-subset of M is determined by how many elements of each type $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ that we choose,

so there are $(r_1+1)(r_2+1)\cdots(r_n+1)$ multi-subsets of M altogether.